# Ubuntu 11.10 stuck on the purple load screen with the 5 progress bullets

Tags: boot

My Ubuntu looks to be stuck at the purple screen with Ubuntu logo.

How can I find what the cause is?

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> it will revive it and reboot, switching for a very short time to a console log before doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to view the log.

Disable splash by using following command

```
sudo mv /etc/init/plymouth.conf /etc/init/plymouth.conf.disabled
```